# Implementation of a recursive function using dask.delayed

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

How can I successfully implement Merge Sort using dask.delayed or with some other dask API. So that it becomes faster with parallelism.

Comment: You may find this useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://gist.github.com/stephanie-wang/5783a0876b25ed750f579278ee8cdeee